# Getting "Invalid JSON primitive" error from MVC AJAX call

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I've read every reference to "Invalid JSON primitive" with no success, so I have no choice but to post my own. I have reduced my code down to the bare minimum and am still getting the error. Here's the "bare minimum":

```
var dataObject = {
    'FirstName': $('#FirstName').val(),
    'LastName': $('#LastName').val()
};

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '@Url.Action("Submit", "Home")',
    contentType: 'application/json;',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: dataObject,
    success: function (result) {
        debugger;
        alert('Success');
    },
    error: function (response) {
        debugger;
        alert('Error');
    }
});
```

I have also tried replacing the dataObject with:

```
var dataObject = {
    'FirstName': 'ES',
    'LastName': 'Dictor'
};
```

Giving no change to my results.

No matter what I do I get (Chrome console):

```
response:
Object {readyState: 4, responseText: "<!DOCTYPE html>
↵<html>
↵    <head>
↵        <titl…nStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
↵-->", status: 500, statusText: "Internal Server Error"}
```

and if I look at response.responseText I see:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Invalid JSON primitive: FirstName.</title>
```

I believe I've tried everything at this point, so it's probably something simple that I'm just missing. Hoping that somebody can see what I can't.

Comment: @DavidTansey The HTML is just giving me the error .. if it wasn't failing I'd expect JSON.

Comment: We would need to see what your post does on the back end. It could be accessing a database incorrectly or referencing pages that don't exist something like that which could result in a internal server error.

Comment: @Demodave my assumption was that the "invalid json primitive" error meant that it wasn't getting that far. Am I incorrect?

Comment: @ESDictor -- sorry, I was not looking closely enough.  Have you tried using `JSON.stringify()` on the data?  Something like `data: JSON.stringify(dataObject)` ?

Comment: @DavidTansey earlier you mentioned the error being returned in HTML, not JSON. Based on that I commented out the "contentType" line and am now getting some success. Not sure if I'm 100% there yet, but I'm closer.

Comment: You need to show you controller method. And since you have not stringified the data, you need to remove the `contentType: 'application/json;',` option.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I finally got this working .. and the answer was removing the contentType. Please add your comment as an answer and I'll mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You posting back an object, not json, so you need to remove the `contentType: 'application/json;',` ajax option so that it uses the default (which is `'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'`) Alternatively you need to use [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) to convert the object to a JSON string.

Side note: It is not necessary to quote the property names. It can be

```
var dataObject = {
    FirstName: $('#FirstName').val(),
    ....
```

Comment: You are correct that it's not necessary to quote the property names, but it actually has no effect to do so. :)